# C++ vectors and errors "no instance of overloaded function"

Tags: c++, vector

I have defined a simple class

```
#pragma once
#include "aSuit.h";
class Card
{
private:
    aSuit theSuit;
public:
    Card(void);
    ~Card(void);
    aSuit getSuit();
    void setSuit(aSuit theSuit);
};
```

Then I defined a vector

```
vector<Card> theCards;
```

then I wanted to push a card on with

```
theCards.push_back(new Card());
```

I go the compile error "no instance of overloaded function".

vector.push_back worked with a vector of strings but not with the classes that I defined.  I am using Visual C++ 2010.  Please help.

Comment: You don't need to use `new` to create objects in C++.

Comment: I love how visual studio class wizard sticks `void` in the parameter list for you.

Comment: You should really use include guards.

Answer (score 11):

```
vector<Card> theCards;
```

This creates a vector of `Card`.

```
theCards.push_back(new Card());
```

This presumes that you have a vector of "pointer to `Card`".

A "pointer to `Card`" and a "`Card`" are **not** the same thing. You mean to say:

```
theCards.push_back(Card());
```

Comment: Or simpler, `theCards.emplace_back();`, or `theCards.resize(theCards.size() + 1);`.